# "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.""

Tags: c#, .net, xml, azure

I am deploying a .Net solution to Azure and am getting the above error when I try to run the page.

I read that System.Web has to be stripped down to this. And that's what I did.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

The solution works locally. Application Insights does not note any errors.  Is there an error log somewhere?  I have no idea what error this could be.  It could be anything.

Comment: [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) and report back with the logs. Should shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need to see the full stack trace echoed to the screen after you deploy to Azure. Set <customErrors mode="Off" /> in your web.config so that you can see what's blowing up. This may be a little faster than Mikael's solution, but Mikael's solution will likely also get you there.

Comment: Neither got me there. :)   custom errors set to off didn't have any effect.  The App Service Log gave me generic and unhelpful "possibilities".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting custom errors to off in your `web.config`.

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off">
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Reference: [customErrors Element (ASP.NET Settings Schema)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Don't forget to turn it back on when you have fixed the issue.

Comment: Tried that.  No effect.